# What do charismatic theologians say about Speaking in Tongues without an interpretation?

Tags: exegesis, speaking-in-tongues

In 1 Corinthians 14:28 it states:

> εαν δε μη η διερμηνευτης σιγατω εν εκκλησια εαυτω δε λαλειτω και τω
> θεω
>
> *But if there be no interpreter, let him keep silence in the church; and let him speak to himself, and to God.*

The conventional charismatic theological interpretation appears to be the thought that a speaker with a message/prayer in tongues should be able to ascertain in advance whether an interpretation is likely to be forthcoming. Without such a confidence, they should not give a message/prayer in tongues in public.

However, one online [commentary](https://www.abarim-publications.com/DictionaryG/s/s-i-om-p-a-om.html) states in reference to σιγατω:

> The verb σιωπαω (siopao) means to be still or quiet. In the classics
> this verb was occasionally also used to describe keeping something a
> secret, or choosing not to speak of something embarrassing or
> damaging.

Have any charismatic theologians interpreted this section as allowing for a person to speak in tongues publicly without an interpretation? But than being quiet afterwards and not interpreting it, lest their giving a public interpretation disclose something embarrassing to a person from another linguistic group?

Are there testimonial cases in which a person has heard a message given in xenolalia tongues that revealed some rather embarrassing personal information at the time?